# what does this mean NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./shared node --harmony

Tags: node.js, redux

I am following this tutorial and i am from windows background

https://github.com/bananaoomarang/isomorphic-redux

May i know what does this mean?

```
"dev": "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./shared node --harmony .",
```

i see the index file on the root directory only

is the equivalent of this on windows will be

```
"dev": "node ./shared node --harmony .",
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same problem on windows and cross-env isn't helping

Answer (score 3):

[`NODE_PATH`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) is like the windows `path` environment variable. Whenever node can't find a file, it looks through the paths in the paths stored in the `NODE_PATH` variable.
So in this case, if you require something from the `shared` folder, node will know how to locate it.
In windows you can't set NODE_PATH in this way, you'll have to set it before you run the node command, or use the [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) module, which allow setting node environment variables unix style in windows:

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./shared node --harmony .",
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, one other question, the file which starts the server is under root directory, how come this is starting the server?

Comment: It's not. It's just adding the shared path to the list of path it can look in for unresolved dependencies.

Comment: cross-env is not working, do i need to include some dependency in package.json? is not recongnized as internal or external command, i have set my node in the environmental variables and it runs from anywhere.

Comment: Sure - `npm install cross-env -D` to install and add it to the package.json dev dependencies.

Comment: one last question if you don't mind, with this command how it is starting the server? the gave the repo location above "dev": "cross-env NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./shared node --harmony .",

Comment: It's not. It's starting node REPL in harmony mode, so you can use ES6.

Comment: Bloody tutorials! It's different in the tutorial you use - `"dev": "npm run start & webpack-dev-server --progress --color"`, and this will start the dev server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120992/discussion-between-ori-drori-and-kobe).